# Editing a link with preg_replace or str_replace issue

Tags: php, href

I have link:
    http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~user/file.php

and I want to make it look like this:
    http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://MyUrl.com/file.php

Essentially I want to replace "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~user" with "MyUrl.com"

Thank you so much for taking the time to help!

One more thing. The file name "file.php" part changes for each page. I don not know ahead what the exact page name will be. Ideally I am wanting to use the php script as an include that will be on every page. I hope this helps clear things up.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you could show us what you have so far that would be really helpful.

Comment: `str_replace('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~user', 'MyUrl.com', $string)`

Answer (score 2):

where's the problem with this?

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-replace.php

```
$newURL = str_replace("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~user","MyUrl.com","http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~user/file.php");
```

UPDATED QUESTION :

you want to swich the `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~user` AND the `file.php`

sorry but at this point why don't you just do

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$filename
```

Comment: +1 According to the question exactly as it was posted this works perfectly. If the x's are supposed to mean something else this would need to be finagled.

Comment: You can understand what he means.

+1

Comment: I updated my question. I am having an issues the the string. The actually file name is unknown and can change for each page.